# Библиотеки протокола gdb

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, gdb

Стоит задача. Написать графическое приложение для Windows на QT. С помощью которого можно коннектиться к удаленной ОС Linux, на которой запущен gdbserver и получать информацию о регистрах, стека и т.д. а также ставить точки останова.

Проанализировав сессию между gdb и gdbserver увидел что при простом создании сессии отправляется более 200 пакетов на подобии $vMustReplyEmpty#3a, $QStartNoAckMode#b0 и т.д

Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека для c++ или QT, которая способна создавать сессии с gdbserver по данному протоколу и обмениваться с ним данными.
Например я ввожу строку i r, а библиотека уже отправляет как $g#67, со всеми необходимыми пакетами и возвращает регистры.

Comment: https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/papers/libgdb/libgdb.html

Comment: [GDB Плагин](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/tree/master/src/plugins/debugger/gdb) к QT Creator